# Laravel - DB Seeder command not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, shell

I've created a custom command functionality for my project, but there is something strange happening at the moment.

First i thought it might had something to do with the `composer dump-autoload` but after adding the exec command it still didn't work.
I do have the 
`seeds` as autoload in my composer.json

```
$this->className = "MyDbSeeder"

$this->call('make:seeder', ['name' => $this->className]);

exec("composer dump-autoload");

sleep(5);

$this->call('db:seed', ['--class' => $this->className]);
/* Response */
// -- ReflectionException  : Class MyDbSeeder does not exist --

/* But when i'm running the exactly same command but not through the `$this->call()` function it works perfectly fine. */

exec("php artisan db:seed --class {$this->className}", $output);
/* Response */
// -- "Database seeding completed successfully." --
```

Of course it does work with the `exec` command, but i don't feel like this is the solution that i need to deliver.

Anyone knows why the regular laravel command ain't working?

Comment: $this->call('db:seed', ['--class' => $this->className]); this usage you call command same runtime.
 
call() method not create new process just handle command

Comment: The class is generated in a different function. And it does exists, it just needs to trigger the command. Will update the code a bit.

Comment: Why do you even want the flow, where you make your seeder programmatically?

Comment: Setting up modules through commandline, on local machine. So thats why its programmaticly. And i don't want it through CRUD. Just want to run the seeders on my test db without running the commands again.

Comment: main problem here dump-autoload not affect current runtime 
you must include manual your seed file